# Why wont the function update the list if using list comprehension but will when using a for loop

Tags: python

This was a question in my computer science course and I can't figure out why the list isn't being updated within the function.

In the code below, function_not_working is what I came up with during the test but ran out of time to find another solution, my friends code, function_working works correctly but both return the correct list update when printing "strings" within the function.

```py
def function_not_working(strings):
    strings = [string[::-1].lower() for string in strings]


def function_working(strings):
    for n in range(0, len(strings)):
        new_string = strings[n].lower()
        new_string = new_string[::-1]
        strings[n] = new_string

# EDIT: THIS PART BELOW IS PART OF THE TESTING AND CANNOT BE EDITED
strings = ["ABC", "aBc", "abc"]
function(strings)
print(strings)
```

For function_not_working
Expected: ['cba', 'cba', 'cba']
Actual: ["ABC", "aBc", "abc"]

Comment: `strings` is a local variable _inside_ `function_not_working()`. Declare it `global` there.

Answer (score 2):

In **function_not_working** you are creating an another list which is not referring to the list passing through the function.That's why it is not updating the strings list. While in **function_working** you are referring to the same list which is passing as argument.

For **function_not_working** to work, find the below code:

```
def function_not_working(strings):
    strings = [string[::-1].lower() for string in strings]
    return strings

strings = ["ABC", "aBc", "abc"]
strings = function_not_working(strings)
print(strings)
```

Comment: Sorry I should have been slightly more specific in the post, the bottom part of the code, the bit without the functions isn't part of the answer but is part of the answer testing, as in it is not able to be edited.

Answer (score 0):

```
def function_not_working():
    global strings
    strings = [string[::-1].lower() for string in strings]


def function_working(strings):
    for n in range(0, len(strings)):
        new_string = strings[n].lower()
        new_string = new_string[::-1]
        strings[n] = new_string


strings = ["ABC", "aBc", "abc"]
function_not_working()
print(strings)
```

I hope you get the answer

Comment: Thank you, I see how it works but still don't understand why it wasn't working in the first place

Comment: In function when you created new list and assigned it to strings which created new list of name strings instead of update global strings list I am updating my answer you will get what you are looking for @ceb

Comment: @ceb Are you familiar with C or C++?

Comment: @MartinBonner No, the first year computer science course only covers python, is C or C++ able to provide a good approach for understanding how global and local variables are different that I should look into?

Comment: @ceb The difference is only partially between globals and locals (and C and C++ don't help here).  The difference is that in one function you are changing the object to which the local variable `strings` refers, and in the other you are changing the values in the existing object.  Because the global `strings` also refers to this (changed) object, you can see the change in the test code.